# QGIS - converting or saving temporary scratch layer

Tags: gis, qgis, grass

I have used the GRASS `v.to.rast` and `r.surf.contour` functions in the processing toolbox of QGIS 3.10.13 to generate DTM raster layers from some vector contour layers. However, the DTM layers are flagged as "Temporary layer only!", and QGIS warns that they "will be discarded after closing QGIS". How do I save them as permanent layers in the current project? I'm new to QGIS so it's possible I've missed something obvious, but I've looked everywhere in the software, along with Google and stackoverflow, with no luck so far. Thanks!

Comment: It's weird, in 3.14 I have an option to save to file or to temporary layer, like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JDEH3uCA1wSlEsZWSqEG3PvT3PoUomnn/view?usp=sharing). Can you right click on your layer and use `save as` option?

Comment: Ah OK - there's no `save as` if I right-click. But I hadn't realised I can save to a file in `v.to.rast`, so I guess I can save to a file and then import that file as a new raster layer. Still seems strange there's no one-click way to permanently save a temporary layer in the same project, but this will do as a workaround. Thank you!

Comment: When you right-click on the layer in your project there should be an option `Export/SaveFeatureAs` and then you can choose a format

Comment: Thanks - that's also there. I guess I was looking for a straight "convert to normal layer", rather than saving and then re-importing. When I choose `Export` > `Save as` then there is also the option to `Add saved file to map` (checkbox at the bottom of the dialogue box). That automatically imports the file back into the current project. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

An old question, I know, but for info if someone comes across this using newer versions of QGIS.

In v3.34 and also in some older versions, by clicking on the icon marking the layer as a temporary scratch layer, a "Save scratch layer" dialog will open. The same dialog as for export-> Save features as, but with the difference that when saved this way, the scratch layer will be replaced with the saved layer with all settings transferred from the scratch layer.

I have a temporary scratch layer that I have made a symbology on:

[image]

Clikcing on the "IC" icon showing that it is a temporary scratch layer allows me to save it:
[image]

And I have a permanent layer in my project
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm an infrequent QGIS user (usually heavy user of ArcGIS Pro).  Needed Lidar DEM merged.  (Raster|Misc|Merge).  had to export as geotiff with a new name.  didn't realize this created a new layer until struggling for a bit with how to make the merged layer permanent.  wound up deleting the "Merged" layer and the two original tiles.  New layer seems to be working fine as I just changed the symbology to hillshade successfully.  A bit of a workaround but now am able to save without a reminder to save the temporary layer.